# Xcode 7 Settings.Bundle everytime I make a change the bundle is empty in settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I created a settings bundle for my iPad app in Xcode 7 iOS 9.

When I make the smallest change, like rename the title of a setting or remove a setting from Root.plist and then I build the app and run it and check the settings in settings, its empty, if I don't change anything it appears, but its just empty. Has anyone come across this issue before?

Is there another step I have to do to change my settings bundle? besides Root.plist ?

Comment: Maybe the change isn't success. The content in the package is immutable.

Comment: apparently I am not the only one with this issue https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9853

Comment: I have exactly the same situation, I don't know if it's a bug. But it wil if more developers complain.

Answer (score 5):

As appearing in the comment of @user979331, the [developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9853) do refer to this problem, so far without a solution.

However it is worth mentioning the technique which is described there to bring the settings back:

> Double-tap the home button to bring the list of active apps, and **drag away** the 'Setting' app to kill it.

If you then open the settings again, your app settings will **appear back as expected !**.